# How do I change PrimaryScreen to AllScreens correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, screenshot, gdi+

I have this method called `Print()` and when I call it, it creates a Bitmap from all the pixels on the primary screen from one point to the other.

However, it only does it for the primary screen (Yes I am aware of the fact that I set it to `Screen.PrimaryScreen` and not `Screen.AllScreens`).

I tried doing so but I had to create an array of all the screens and thats where I got stuck. How would I achieve the exact same thing as with this method but for multiple screens?

```
private void Print()
{
    string path;
    path = "%AppData%\\Image.png";
    path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);

    Bitmap bt;
    Graphics screenShot;

    bt = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    screenShot = Graphics.FromImage(bt);
    screenShot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    bt.Save(path);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the bounds of the screens using [`Rectangle.Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.union(v=vs.110).aspx) method and LINQ:

```
var bounds = Screen.AllScreens.Select(s => s.Bounds).Aggregate(Rectangle.Union);
```

Then simply replace `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds` with `bounds` variable in your code.

Comment: This is also a very good solution! Never used LINQ before but I've heard its very powerful!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Screens.AllScreens()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens(v=vs.110).aspx) method to return an array of all the screens and then loop over that:

```
foreach (var screen in Screens.AllScreens())
{
    bt = new Bitmap(screen.Bounds.Width, screen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    ....
}
```

This will take a separate bitmap image of each screen. If you want a single bitmap for all screens then you'll need to either stitch these bitmaps together or use [Ivan's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40489357/59303) to get the combined bounds of all the screens.

Comment: This was what I was looking for, didnt know it was that easy, I made it so much more complicated in my head!

Answer (score 0):

You say you are going from one point to another, so to get the screen that contains the point you can use [Screen.FromPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.frompoint(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
Screen screen = Screen.FromPoint(point);
```

Then wherever you use `Screen.PrimaryScreen` just use `screen` instead.

Comment: That is a very good approach and I was trying to explain how the method was working. But I will write this down as a little note next time im doing something like this, thanks!